# Why does my Spinner constructor not work as intended?

Tags: java, javafx, constructor, spinner

If I create an instance of a `Spinner` using the constructor with arguments, that spinner will not show the given values. But when using a `SpinnerValueFactory()` and apply it to the spinner, it loads the initial value and sets min,max.

The documentation says:

> `Spinner(double min, double max, double initialValue, double amountToStepBy)`
>
> Creates a `Spinner` instance with the value factory set to be an instance of `SpinnerValueFactory.DoubleSpinnerValueFactory`.

So I would expect the constructor to set its own `SpinnerValueFactory`. My question is, why does that not work? How should one use those constructors?

In order to keep my code better readable and shorter, I would love to only use the constructor without an individual `SpinnerValueFactory()` for each Spinner (I need a couple of different ones).

What I would expect to work, but which does not:
controller.java:

```
@FXML Spinner<Integer> mySpinner;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

    mySpinner = new Spinner(1, 100, 1, 1);

}
```

What works:

```
SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory myFactory = new SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory(1, 100, 1, 1);
@FXML Spinner<Integer> mySpinner;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
    mySpinner.setValueFactory(myFactory);
}
```

Comment: What *does not work*? What happens and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Annotating a field with `@FXML` means that the instance of that field will be defined in the FXML-file. Imagine the FXML-file as separate class, and the spinner from that separate class gets injected into your class.

Comment: @Turing85 Uhmm ... Ah, ok I see. Thank you for the explanation. And when call `.setValueFactory()` inside `initialize()` I overwrite the instance from .FXML? Is there then any way to use the constructor to install the ValueFactory on instantiation in the .FXML file?